# How to output mocha logs as gitlab artifacts from a docker compose container?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab and it's ci/cd system to build, test and deploy my code.  I've set it up so my builds and my tests are in separate containers:

```
image: docker:latest

...

callback_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --no-cache -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID

callback_test:
  stage: test
  image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
  script:
    - cd test/
    - >
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
      --build
      --abort-on-container-exit
      --exit-code-from hellosign-callback-listener-tests
```

Within my Dockerfile for the tests I run the command: `ENTRYPOINT [ "mocha", "--config",  "./test/.mocharc.js"]`

Now because of the way we have things setup, the output from docker is not displayed in the gitlab ci/cd view, instead I think it's forwarded to logstash which then pushes it to our ELK stack so it can be viewed on Kibana.  At the moment this isn't reliable, so I thought the best way would be to use [gitlabs artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts).

Gitlab doesn't seem to have a custom mochajs artifact integration, so I'm unsure how best to get the output from mocha into an artifact for me to download from gitlab and view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the first thing you need to change is writing your tests somewhere as the current entrypoint command doesn't write the tests anywhere.

Switch the entrypoint command to: `ENTRYPOINT mocha --config ./test/.mocharc.js --reporter json > results.json` this will use the [JSON reporter](https://mochajs.org/#json) to create a JSON report in the directory you run the tests from.

You'll then need to make some big changes to the .gitlab-ci.yml file in the way you go about building and running the tests.

```
image: docker:latest

callback_test:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    untracked: false
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - results.json
  script:
    - cd test/
    - docker build -f "Dockerfile" -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE-tests:$CI_PIPELINE_ID --build-arg SUT_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_PIPELINE_ID .
    - docker run --name $CI_PIPELINE_ID -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE-tests:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - docker wait $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - docker cp $CI_PIPELINE_ID:/usr/src/app/results.json $CI_PROJECT_DIR/results.json
```

So we're using docker to build our testing image, and we're passing it a base image to use.  The base image is from my build docker image and my test Dockerfile looks like:

```
ARG SUT_IMAGE
FROM $SUT_IMAGE
...
npm i -g mocha
```

We're then running the image we just built and giving it a unique name, I'm just using the pipeline id for that.

We then wait for an exit code from the image, because otherwise it'll exit slightly too early and your results file will be blank.

Then we copy the results file from the image to the project directory.

Since we're removing docker-compose, any environment variables will now have to come from a `.env` file and something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) instantiated in your mocha common.js setup.

There are still a few issues with this.  A failing test will still set the test stage as passed due the exit code from the test image not mattering to the rest of the script, so this needs a lot of improvement.